# How to install BIOVIA Discovery Studio on Lubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, libraries

I have BIOVIA_2021.DS2021Client.bin (278.7MB) and as guided by

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/353035302_Method_for_installing_Biovia_Discovery_Studio_Viewer_2021_in_Linux_Mint_201_or_Ubuntu_2004

which are

1. Download BIOVIA_2021.DS2021.Client.bin to ~/Desktop
2. chmod +x BIOVIA_2021.DS2021.Client.bin
3. ./BIOVIA_2021.DS2021.Client.bin --noexec --target ~/progs/BIOVIA2021
4. cd ~/progs/BIOVIA2021
5. Open "install_DSClient.sh" with a text editor
6. Change "#!/bin/sh" to "#!/bin/bash"
7. Insert "shopt -s expand_aliases" above "alias echoe="echo -e" and save file
8. Make executable: "chmod +x install_DSClient.sh"
9. Run installer: "./install_DSClient.sh"
10. When prompted to select install location, choose [2], write
    "~/progs/BIOVIA2021/DiscoveryStudio2021", return, choose [1], return, choose [1]
11. cd ~/progs/BIOVIA2021/DiscoveryStudio2021

12.(he forgot numbering may be 11 to 13)

13. cd lp_installer
14. chmod +x lp_setup_linux.sh
15. ./lp_setup_linux.sh --noexec --target ~/progs/BIOVIA2021
16. cd ~/progs/BIOVIA2021/LicensePack/etc
17. ./lp_config
18. Open "lp_echvars" in a text editor
19. change "#! /bin/csh -f" to "#! /bin/tcsh" and save and close file
20. ./lp_echovars
21. cd ~/progs/BIOVIA2021/DiscoveryStudio2021/bin
22. ./config_lp_location ~/progs/BIOVIA2021/LicensePack/
23. copy your copy of "libpng15.so.15" into
    ~/progs/BIOVIA2021/DiscoveryStudio2021/lib

You will also need to locate a source for libpng15.so.15. This will be
added to the ~/progs/BIOVIA2021/DiscoveryStudio2021/lib directory in step 23.

24. cd ~/progs/BIOVIA2021/DiscoveryStudio2021/bin
25. Open "DiscoveryStudio2021 in a text editor; change "ACCELRYS_DEBUG=0" to
    "ACCELRYS_DEBuG=1". Then when DSV is started via the terminal, you will get a
    verbose readout that can be inspected for errors
26. ./DiscoveryStudio2021 and follow the instructions on the dialog boxes that
    appear
27. If all goes well, enjoy using DSV2021

but in 23rd step I don't understand how to bring **libpng15.so.15** file.

can anyone suggest me the sourse of libpng15.so.15?

Answer (score 2):

You can download the source for libpng15.so.15 from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng15/1.5.30/). Find the .tar.gz or .tar.xz archive and download it.

Then, unzip the package, `cd` into the directory with the source code, and run `./configure` and then `make install`.

The library should be installed to `/usr/local/lib`, and you can copy it from there or symlink it.

Answer (score 1):

Copy libpng14.so.14 and paste then just change the name of libpng14.so.14 to libpng15.so.15 then run the DS studio as described above.